# Integrating PayPal with a WebMatrix-based site (Razor/C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have spent countless hours reading over the docs on PayPal's site and also on their x.com site, and have searched all over the web for this, but unfortunately, I am in need of some help.

I have a service that I offer on my site, and all I am trying to do is to send the customer off to the paypal site (which I can do), and let them pay (which they can do), and then have them be redirected back to my site once the payment has been approved/made (which is what happens), but that's where it all stops...

I have tried so many tutorials and samples out there, and it's becoming quite difficult here. I need to be able to do simple checks on my site (IPN thing). So that I know whether or not someone has paid for the service at paypal, so I know whether or not I should activate the service on my site for that particular customer.

I know there is a PayPal Helper, but that does not help me in this situation since it does not deal with the IPN stuff.

Note: This service is not a subscription service, it is just a one-off payment.

I would really appreciate your help on this, I really am stuck and don't know what to do next.

## UPDATE

So I have tested the script which @Bobby provided in his answer, and I am receiving an error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Runtime Error 
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>


Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

NOTE: After turning CustomErrors OFF, I still receive this message.

## UPDATE #2

When I try to output the result of string ipnPost = strRequest; it displays a message "status is invalid - form_charset=UTF8"

That's all it says. I don't know why..

## LATEST UPDATE -

I am now receiving the following error using the following code:

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before
>   calling [Begin]GetResponse.  Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: You must
>   write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling
>   [Begin]GetResponse.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 34:      Line 35:      Line 36:     StreamReader streamIn = new
>   StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()); Line 37:
>   string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();streamOut.Close(); Line 38: 
>   streamIn.Close();
>
> Source File:
>   c:\HostingSpaces\sssssssss\sssssss.com\wwwroot\Checkout\Status.cshtml
>   Line: 36
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ProtocolViolationException: You must write ContentLength bytes to the
>   request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse.]
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +7769822
>   ASP._Page_Checkout_Status_cshtml.Execute() in
>   c:\HostingSpaces\ssssss\ssssssss.com\wwwroot\Checkout\Status.cshtml:36
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +369
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +157
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext
>   context) +294
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

```
@using System.Collections.Generic
@using System.Text
@using System.Web
@using System.Web.UI
@using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@using System.ComponentModel

@{
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Checkout | sssss";

    string postUrl = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postUrl);

    //Set values for the request back
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
    string strRequest = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(param);
    string ipnPost = strRequest;
    strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
    req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

    //for proxy
    //WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://url:port#"));
    //req.Proxy = proxy;

    //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
    StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), 
                             System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    streamOut.Write(strRequest);

    streamOut.Close();

    StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
    streamIn.Close();

    /*/ logging ipn messages... be sure that you give write
    // permission to process executing this code
    string logPathDir = ResolveUrl("Messages");
    string logPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.txt", 
                     Server.MapPath(logPathDir), DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    File.WriteAllText(logPath, ipnPost);
    /*/

}
@if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
{
    /*---------------- WILL DO OTHER CHECKS LATER    ------------------*/
    //check the payment_status is Completed
    <p>status is verified</p>
    //check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    //check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    //check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    //process payment
}
else if (strResponse == "INVALID")
{
    //log for manual investigation
    <p>status is invalid.</p>

<p>@ipnPost</p>
}
else
{
    //log response/ipn data for manual investigation
    <p>status is invalid.</p>
<p>@ipnPost</p>
}
```

Comment: Is this a problem with the CallBack from Paypal? If you look in your IIS logs can you see Paypal sending you transaction info to a url? Is the url the right place?

Comment: Thanks for asking, @Neil, upon looking in the IIS logseventhing seemed pretty normal to me. :/